# Comparator.comparing for Map.Entry in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given following code:

```
@Test
public void test7() {
    Map<String, Integer> sortedData = new HashMap<>();
    sortedData.put("One", 1);
    sortedData.put("Two", 2);
    sortedData.put("Three", 3);

    Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> stream = sortedData.entrySet().stream();
    List<String> sorted = stream
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It succeeds to compile, but when I change

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
```

to

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())
```

the compiler complains that `Non static method can't be referenced in static context`

I could imagine that it is because `getValue` is not a static method of `Map.Entry`, but I can't explain the problem here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's interesting,

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue).reversed ())
```

works.

Perhaps using raw `Map.Entry` confuses the compiler.

BTW, this also works:

```
.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)))
```

(`Collections.reverseOrder(this)` is what `reversed()` returns)

Comment: Thanks @eran. The IDEA IDE indicates that `<String,Integer>` in `Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue)` is redundant, :-)

Comment: @Tom that's funny

Comment: Target type inference doesn’t work through method invocation chains, therefore the types for the first invocation have to be inferred using the argument, thus, either `Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue` or `(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e) -> e.getValue()` is needed. Or you change the code from an invocation chain to nested invocation: `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))` or just `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())`…